# OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded при параметрах -Xmx8192M -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

Tags: java, junit, jvm, сборщик-мусора

jUnit тесты работают с большими объемами данных, в частности, данная ошибка возникает, когда считываем данные из базы в объект.

ОЗУ - 16 Гб, 4 виртуальных процессора

когда возникла ошибка

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor47.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
```

то я добавил параметр `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`
но получил следующую ошибку:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.copy(Field.java:150)
    at java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.copyField(ReflectAccess.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.copyField(ReflectionFactory.java:309)
    at java.lang.Class.copyFields(Class.java:3115)
    at java.lang.Class.getFields(Class.java:1557)
    at main.java.DataFormat.DbTable.loadObjectFromResultSet(DbTable.java:101)
    at main.java.DataFormat.DbTable.getEntities(DbTable.java:57)
```

все параметры JVM `-Xmx8192M -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

в момент появления ошибки были следующие параметры системы: 
ОЗУ стабильно на 46% (7400Мб), ЦПУ 77%-82% (82% в момент появления ошибки)

подскажите, как исправить данную проблему?

**Спарвка**

> 3. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>
> Данная ошибка может возникнуть как при переполнении первой, так и
>   второй областей. Связана она с тем, что памяти осталось мало и GC
>   постоянно работает, пытаясь высвободить немного места. Данную ошибку
>   можно отключить с помощью параметра -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit, но,
>   конечно же, её надо не отключать, а либо решать проблему утечки
>   памяти, либо выделять больше объема, либо менять настройки GC.

**Ответ**
`String` объект слишком много весит. а у меня там очень много стрингов. Для примера, посчитали файл, который весит 250 МБ, имеет 1600 символов в строке и 220 000 строк. Заполняю в `ArrayList<String> lines`, где каждая строка записана как объект из 250 полей, которые принимают значение из 1600 символов. Такой объект весил чуть больше `6Гб`.

**Решение:** увеличил память до `14Гб`. теперь проблема в том, что 6Гбайтный объект не помещается в куче, надо думать что-то другое и пожертвовать временем выполнения теста.

Comment: А где этот параметр задаётся? -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В данном случае ошибка `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` говорит о том, что Вы пытаетесь обработать такой объем данных который не помещается в память. В приведенной Вами справке упомянуто, что ошибка выбрасывается, когда область памяти, занимаемая только, что созданными объектами переполняется. Плюс к этому в трассировке стека видно, что ваши классы (

```
at main.java.DataFormat.DbTable.loadObjectFromResultSet(DbTable.java:101)
at main.java.DataFormat.DbTable.getEntities(DbTable.java:57)
```

) в момент получения ошибки как раз пытаются выгрузить данные из базы.

Поэтому простой и неутешительный вывод из вышесказанного тестируйте на меньшем объеме данных или выделяйте больший объем под выгружаем данные(-Xmx12000M) если они туда поместятся, то ошибка исчезнет. Настраивать сборку мусора в данном случае бесполезно т.к. GC не сможет удалить загружаемые объекты потому как они еще используются.

Comment: посмотрим. результат увидим завтра

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, больше 8Гб под Xmx не рекомендуется выделять

Comment: @Senior Automator, но если очень хочется то можно.

Comment: @Senior Automator, а если серьезно то зависит от задачи, и если у Вас данные не помещаются в память то выбора у Вас не будет либо обрабатывать их частями, обрабатывать не в памяти(а например в БД) или увеличить допустимы размер heapа.

Comment: установил 12Гб ОЗУ, не помогло.  хочу отметить, что данные базы, выгруженные  в java объект занимают 138 Мб. Тащить данные поочереди - очень долго, так как займет дополнительных 30часов

Comment: @Senior Automator, опишите задачу и данные более подробно желательно с примеров с программой в смысле.

Comment: @Senior Automator если данные по очереди займут 30 часов, то у Вас что-то с реализацией чтения из БД.

Comment: Согласен особенно если там данных на 138 Мб, единственное может они выбираются из нескольких Тб данных. @Senior Automator, Вы не фильтруете случайно данные в памяти?

Comment: каждый запрос jdbs занимает время. если 200к записей в бд читать сразу -то занимает одно время. если читать по очереди, то совершенно другое. пробовал через Hibernate. во-первых, Hibernate жрет 3 раза больше памяти, чем сама база, во-вторых, ооочень медленный. 
работаю напрямую через jdbs. один раз получаю resultSet и прохожу по полям сразу. такой способ позволил оочень быстро ускорить тест. на несколько порядков. 
Могу предположить. что resultSet  много весит. но надо проверить это

Comment: @Senior Automator похоже неправильно используешь JDBC раз такой результат.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator если у вас данных на 138 МБ, но они не помещаются в 12 ГБ памяти, то у вас явно что-то не так в коде. Добавьте ваш код (желательно, [mcve]) в вопрос, чтобы мы могли понять, что происходит.

Comment: String объект слишком много весит. а у меня там очень много стрингов. Для примера, посчитали файл, который весит 250 МБ, имеет  1600 символов в строке и 220 000 строк. Заполняю в ArrayList<String> lines, где каждая строка записана как объект из 250 полей, которые принимают значение из 1600 символов.
Такой объект весил чуть больше 6Гб. 

Решение: увеличил память до 14Гб.  теперь проблема в том, что 6Гбайтный объект поместить в куче или думать что-то другое.

Comment: @Senior Automator, IMHO лучше тестировать на меньшем объеме данных, а решение поместите себе в ответ что бы было сразу тем кто будет читать вопрос.

Answer (score 7):

Начту с основ для лучшего понимания ошибки.

JVM имеет две области памяти: **Heap Memory** и **Non-Heap Memory**.

- **Heap Memory** - хранит объекты;
- **Non-Heap Memory** - хранит параметры методов, примитивные типы и т.д.

[image: JVM memory structure]

В Вашем случае происходит переполнение *Heap Memory*, т.к. очень много создается объектов, которые не вмещаются в *Heap Memory*. Решить проблему можно увеличив Heap Memory (ключ -Xmx), что не всегда помогает, т.к. объем данных может быть больше чем доступно ОЗУ, поэтому лучше реализовать обработку данных из БД порционно, т.е. выгружать часть данных, чтобы объекты поместились в памяти, затем убивать их (присваивать `null`, чтобы *GC* разгрузить), замет следующею часть и т.д.

**P.S.** Стоит понимать, что *Heap* не равно *ОЗУ*. Heap - это только зарезервированная память для JVM, больше данного резерва JVM использовать не может даже, если ОЗУ в избытке.